# Which charset is this?

Tags: fonts, character-encoding

Anyone knows what is the charset name for the one that contains only alphanum chars, **without** `I`,`J`,`L`,`Q`,`O`,`U` ?
That's 30 characters in total, letters can either be in lower or upper case (no mix up).

It's actually pretty close the [Crockford's base32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32#Crockford.27s_Base32), but goes even further by removing the `J` and `Q`.

**Amendment**

This is typically used in pharmaceutical product marking.
As described in the following European Federation of Pharmaceutical Industries and Associations ([EFPIA](http://www.efpia.eu/)) [document](http://www.efpia.eu/uploads/images/EFPIA%20European%20Pack%20Coding%20Guideline%20V3_6%20%28Final%29.pdf) extract (page 6):

> The serial number is preceded by the AI 21 and adheres to the GS1
>   specification where this field is a variable length (up to 20 digits)
>   alphanumeric field followed by a Group Separator (GS) character (to
>   delimit it from the next field unless it is the last field). The
>   serial number will be unique per product code (i.e. not per batch or
>   per product code-batch code pair). EFPIA recommends two further
>   restrictions:
>
> - The serial number character string should only contain either lower case or upper case letters, not a mixture.
> - The alphanumeric range shall include the digits 0-9 and the letters of the western alphabet but exclude the following letters: i, j, l, o,
>     q and u. (I J L O Q U) **This gives a range of 30 different alphanumeric
>     character options to work with if required**.

Comment: Base30? Base encoding can use any substitution alphabet you like, have you got any real examples?

Comment: "not a charset" unless you also tell us where you found it. Without that information, it's just a bunch of letters without any meaning or intended purposes.